# "Unexpected Error While Parsing Value" using InvokeApiAsync Method of Xamarin Azure Mobile Services Component 1.1.0

Tags: azure, xamarin.android, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I was trying to use "InvokeApiAsync" methohd of Xamarin Azure Mobile Services Component 1.1.0 as mentioned below :

```
var result = await _nativeClient.InvokeApiAsync ("insertsample", HttpMethod.Post, null);
```

I get an exception saying :

```
  {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing                value: O. Path '', line 0, position 0.
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ReadFrom (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Load (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Parse (System.String json) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.StringExtensions.ParseToJToken (System.String response) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient+<InvokeApiAsync>d__6.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Any pointers on how to solve this issue?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default overload of InvokeApiSync expects a JSON response. It sounds like you are not returning one. Try this:

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
    response.send(200, {}); // note the empty JSON object
}
```

Alternatively, if you do not wish to return JSON, you can use a different overload of InvokeApiAsync that returns a HttpResponseMessage and then parse the response however you wish.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and get back to you. Also you replied on my other question regarding Build Warnings. I suppose if this solves the JSON issue then it might not be co-related after all :)

Comment: It works! Although this behaviour is different from the .NET behaviour! Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is different from .NET? I was just able to reproduce in a C# Win 8 application using the NuGet package. Maybe this is a recent regression? If you have time to try again from .NET it would be great to know if you are seeing the same behavior that I am.

Comment: No I guess even .NET is having issues. I saw your code you used to test this. I'm going to give this a try on my side now.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue when returning JSON that was read from a file. It was stored as UTF-8 but also had the BOM (0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF). JSON.NET is not expecting it, so you get the "Unexpected character" error.

Make sure you strip the BOM if present.

Comment: There is nothing being returned from the azure mobile service. Just a response.send(statusCodes.OK);

Comment: Hmm.. not sure how JSON.NET handles an empty response, since that's not really valid JSON. It should either be {} for empty object, or [] for empty collection.

Comment: It is actually Node.js script which returns the response. Thanks!